# How elementary can my question be?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Sometime I find myself dealing with a problem that through the right Google search I'll find the solution to it. Usually, it will take me 1-2 minutes to post a question in the website and 10 times that to search Google for a solution (most of the time is spent on finding the right term to search).

On one hand, searching for a solution by myself is the best approach, on the other hand, this is a Q&A site which should include some beginner solutions....

I have found [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18802/how-silly-can-a-question-be) which is similar to mine. From what I understood, it is OK to ask an elementary question so long it is related to the topic of the Q&A and might help somebody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policy on this has varied over the years, so if you're looking for a canonical answer, I'd recommend only looking at those from within the last 6-12 months (or so).

In this case, I recommend two MSO questions and one blog post:

- [Can we prevent some of the low-quality questions from entering our system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system)
- [Clarify SE's policy on easy questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76928/clarify-ses-policy-on-easy-questions)
- [Are Some Questions Too Simple?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

Or in other words: Yes, there are questions that are too simple/elementary/silly/basic/easy/low-quality to be welcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

It's OK to ask an elementary question if you show that you've done some research and have checked that the question hasn't been asked previously.

Otherwise you're wasting people's time.